# How to keep (or force) a fomat to whole text document in Markdown?

Tags: html, text, formatting, markdown

I am pretty sure the answer to my question must be available somewhere, but I am exhausted by looking for it.

My question is very straight forward.

For instance:

```
**This is a sentence.

I want everything to be in BOLD.
Why the line break it?**
```

I need the whole text to be bold. Please don't simply suggest to remove the gap line there. There are many reasons in my work that I cannot do that. I am working on document and I need to keep them exactly the same, while viewing them differently to users.

I appreciate if you can help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bold each paragraph individually:

```
**This is a sentence.**

**I want everything to be in BOLD.
Why the line break it?**
```

Note that bold is "inline" while a paragraph is a "block". Inline elements cannot extend outside of a block. Therefore, each paragraph needs its own inline elements.

This is not just Markdown, but related directly to HTML, of which Markdown is a subset. In fact, if you tried to force a bold element in HTML to wrap multiple paragraphs, the browser would auto-close the bold element at the first block level tag after the bold element is opened. In other words, the browser will extrapolate meaning you did not intend because the HTML spec requires it to. So you have to follow the rules and not try to extend inline elements outside of block level elements.